# I am new to js and tried making a number guessing game and it did not work

Tags: javascript

> *i started learning JavaScript yesterday and i was trying to make a number guessing game in JavaScript but it didnt work, instead it would just randomly say this is to big this is to high and i dont know whats wrong with it, heres the code:*

```js
console.log('guess a number beetwen 0 - 10');
var status = true;
while (status == true){
  const input = prompt(' ');
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 + 1));
  if (Number(input) == Number(rand)){
    console.log('Good job! you got it.');
    status = false;
  } else if (Number(input) > Number(rand)){
    console.log('too high try again!');
  } else if (Number(input) < Number(rand)){
    console.log('too small try again');
  } else {
    console.error('please enter a number');
  }
}
```

Comment: You are taking a new random value on each iteration. Move rand outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time around the loop, you're picking a new random number, so every time you guess, the number you're trying to match is different.

What you probably wanted was to pick a random number *outside* of the loop, so that it stays the same between guesses.

You just need to move the "const rand ..." line above the beginning of the "while" loop

Answer (score 1):

First, It is running an infinite loop using `while(true)` until your entered number and random number generated match so there is a possibility you will see multiple messages till then.

Second, since you are using `Math.rand()`, it is generating random numbers, and therefore, whichever condition is matching it is logging that message.

Comment: The loop is not infinite, it stops when there is a correct guess.

Comment: @IMSoP: That's true. I should modify my statement. It will keep running and shows message until that condition is met.